# In Linux's net/ipv4/udp.c, why does a UDP packet need to be processed by xfrm4_policy_check()?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

```
int udp_queue_rcv_skb(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb) {
    struct udp_sock *up = udp_sk(sk);
    int rc;
    int is_udplite = IS_UDPLITE(sk);

    /*
     * Charge it to the socket, dropping if the queue is full.
     */
    if (!xfrm4_policy_check(sk, XFRM_POLICY_IN, skb))
        goto drop;

    nf_reset(skb);
```

I'm reading the code in Linux net/ipv4/udp.c. Can anyone explain to me why an UDP packet need to run through xfrm_policy_check()?

As far as I know the function return:

- **true**: non-IPsec packet / valid IPsec packet
- **false**: invalid IPsec packet

I might have misunderstood the function return value, as do not entirely understand the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xfrm4_policy_check` function checks the packet against [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) policies. The return value of this function is 1 if the packet is allowed to be processed, and zero if it is not. For example, IPsec might decide to drop the packet if `skb->ip_summed` is not set to `CHECKSUM_UNNECESSASRY` and packet fails a checksum.

Comment: An `UDP` packet will obviously not have any IPsec policy (SA?) so why bother? Unless it is `ESPinUDP` Packet which is handled by the other code ..

Comment: @24hours: I think it can check at least checksum if not in routing mode and reject corrupt packages.